# How do I create order statistics by group in R?

Tags: r

How do I compute order statistics by group in R. I want to aggregate results according to a column and then return only 1 row per group. That row should be the n-th element of the group according to some ordering. Ideally I would like to use base functions only.

```
x <- data.frame(Group=c("A","A", "A", "C", "C"), 
                Name=c("v", "u", "w", "x", "y"), 
                Quantity=c(3,3,4,2,0))
> x
  Group Name Quantity
1     A    v        3
2     A    u        3
3     A    w        4
4     C    x        2
5     C    y        0
```

I want to take nth highest based on an ordering on Quantity and then Name. For N=2 this is

```
  Group Name Quantity
1     A    u        3
5     C    y        0

For N=1
  Group Name Quantity
3     A    w        4
4     C    x        2
```

I tried the following but I get a uninformative error message.

```
 aggregate.data.frame(x, list(x$Group), function(y){ max(y[,'Quantity'])})
 Error in `[.default`(y, , "Quantity") (from #1) : incorrect number of dimensions"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with

```
do.call(rbind, by(x, x$Group, function(x)
      x[order(-x$Quantity, x$Name),][1,]))
```

per someone else's suggestion. I found it suited my thought process a bit better than the other posted solutions (which I appreciate).

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- 
    data.frame(
        Group = c("A","A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A") , 
        Name = c("v", "u", "w", "x", "y" ,"v", "u") , 
        Quantity = c(3,3,4,2,0,4,1)
    )

# sort your data to start..
# note that Quantity vs. Group and Name
# are sorted in different directions,
# so the -as.numeric() flips them
x <- 
    x[ 
        order( 
            -as.numeric( x$Group ) , 
            x$Quantity , 
            -as.numeric( x$Name ) , 
            decreasing = TRUE 
        ) , 
    ]
# once your data frame is sorted the way you want your Ns to occur, the rest is easy

# rank your data..  
# just create the numerical order, 
# but within each group..
# (or you could add those ranks directly to the data frame if you like)
ranks <- 
    unlist( 
        tapply( 
            order( x$Group ) , 
            as.numeric( x$Group ) , 
            order 
        ) 
    )

# N = 1
x[ ranks == 1 , ]

# N = 2
x[ ranks == 2 , ]
```

Comment: I think your 'N' and 'ranks' should agree.  `x[ ranks == 2, ]$Name` returns `c('v', 'y')` rather than `c('u', 'y')` as desired.  I fell for the same trap at first.

Comment: With the edit, you're taking the minimum value of `Name` within each group, which happens to be correct for the example, as there is only one value for `Name` for the rank 1 case, but is not correct in general.

Answer (score 1):

Some aggregate-merge magic:

```
f <- function(x, N) {
  sel <- function(x) {                                   # Choose the N-th highest value from the set, or lowest element if there < N unique elements.  Is there a built-in for this? 
    z <- unique(x)                                       # This assums that you wan the N-th highest unique value.  Simply don't filter by unique if not.
    z[order(z, decreasing=TRUE)][min(N, length(z))]
  }

  xNq <- aggregate(Quantity ~ Group, data=x,   sel)      # Choose the N-th highest quantity within each "Group"
  xNm <- merge(x, xNq)                                   # Add the matching "Name" values
  x <- aggregate(Name ~ Quantity + Group, data=xNm, sel) # Choose the N-th highest Name in each group
  x[c('Group', 'Name', 'Quantity')]                      # Put into original order
}


> f(x, 2)
##   Group Name Quantity
## 1     A    u        3
## 2     C    y        0

> f(x, 1)
##   Group Name Quantity
## 1     A    w        4
## 2     C    x        2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# define ordering function, increasing on Quantity, decreasing on Name
in.order <- function(group) with(group, group[order(Quantity, -rank(Name)), ])

# set desired rank for each Group
N <- 2

# get Nth row by Group, according to in.order
group.rows <- by(x, x$Group, function(group) head(tail(in.order(group), N), 1))

# collapse rows into data.frame
do.call(rbind, group.rows)

#   Group Name Quantity
# A     A    u        3
# C     C    y        0
```

The reason you're seeing that error with `aggregate.data.frame` is because this function applies `FUN` over each column, according to the `by` argument, not each subset of the full `data.frame` (that's what the `by` function is for, as you can see above). When using `aggregate`, whatever you supply to `FUN` should be accepting columns, not `data.frame`s. In your example, you're trying to index vector `y` like a `data.frame`, hence the dimension error.

Comment: +1 for this is the simplest solution!Might I suggest to add a parameter in in.order function for dec/inc order..

Comment: @agstudy that's a valid suggestion. If I were going to use this myself, I'd certainly do so. For the sake of brevity, though, I'm going to leave it as is.